# Are there limitation on converting or casting timestamp column to time in redshift database without timezone?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am working with Amazon Redshift database using Postgresql. I have a timestamp column which I need to convert over to just time. I have used the following line to determine column properties:

```
select * from pg_table_def where tablename = 'tableA'
```

This line gives the detail that the timestamp column is type 'timestamp without time zone'.

To test casting method in Postgresql i tried the following line:

```
select '2016-10-01 12:12:12'::time
```

which casts the timestamp to `'12:12:12'`

I want to recreate this for the entire column 'timestamp' in my table, but run into the following error, when I run the following line:

```
select timestamp::time from tableA

'SQL Error [500310] [0A000]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;
```

**Is there a limitation on timestamp columns with NO timezone to convert them into just time?**

**What am I doing wrong in which each record of the column is not converting to time?**

--edit--
@halil here is the modified line I have been using from yours.

```
select (extract(hour from timestamp) || ':' || extract(minute from timestamp) || ':' || extract(second from timestamp)) as my_time from tableA
```

--edit--
@halil here is the lines used to subtract timestamp. All I doing is subtracting the next timestamp from the previous one:

```
select eventtimestamp - lead(eventtimestamp) over (order by eventtimestamp)
from ga_visit_events
```

Comment: Is it Redshift or Postgres? Redshift is based on such an old version of Postgres that those two aren't really the same any more.

Comment: its redshift and I am using postgresql in redshift

Comment: There is no "using postgres **in** redshift". It's either the one or the other. It can't be both.

Comment: I am using redshift then.

Answer (score 0):

I checked redshift documentation and could not find a proper fucntion to do this. 
But you can use this query to get what you want

```
select date_part(h, your_tm)||':'||date_part(min, your_tm)||':'||date_part(sec, your_tm) from your_table
```

Comment: I have been using a modified version see in edit. but the issue with this I am having is that I need to use mathematical functions on the time, just simple subtraction in this case. So when we use your line or my line the column gets converted into text. In which case I can not do anything with it.

Comment: why do not you do math on timestamps and convert them to string later ?

Comment: I have done the math on the timestamps but it gives me really screwy results for example see edit for timestamp subtraction above. The results I get look something like this:

"4511137 years 4 mons -00:00:10.184"